# Default to "I'm Feeling Lucky" for non-URL search terms in Firefox address bar

Tags: firefox

Example:

I want to be able to type "Microsoft" in the Firefox address bar and have it take me to the "I'm Feeling Lucky" result for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind - found the answer.

about:config > keyword.url = http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=

Comment: so mark it as a valid answer